# Float arithmetic operation yields value = 0

Tags: c

The below program yields value = 0.000000, although the format specifier is that of a float.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
        printf ("%f", 5/9);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: `When integers are divided, the result of the / operator is the algebraic quotient with any fractional part discarded`

Answer (score 3):

The expression `5/9` has two integer arguments and so is evaluated used integer division. Hence the result is `0`.

You then invoke undefined behaviour by passing an `int` to a `%f` format specifier.

Change at least one of the operands to a floating point value to use floating point division:

```
printf("%f", 5.0/9.0);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 printf ("%f", 5/9);
```

`5 / 9` is an integer division. The expression yields an `int` but `f` requires a `float` or a `double` argument.

Change the call to:

```
printf ("%f", 5 / 9.0);
```

to perform a floating-point division and have a `double` argument.

Answer (score 0):

`5` and `9` is integer. Division of two integer will be always integer. Make one of them a float or a double

```
 printf ("%f", 5.0/9);
```

or

```
 printf ("%f", 5/9.0);
```

Comment: `5.0` and `9.0` are not `float`, they are `double`